# How do I see output from UnitTests in VS2013?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, resharper, xunit.net

I'm using XUnit, and in both the Visual Studio Test Explorer window and the Resharper Unit Test runner window, I'm no longer seeing the "output" hyperlink that would show the contents of `WriteLine` commands.

Is there a setting in the IDE that I need to change?

Comment: Windows Test Explorer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a change in xunit2. It no longer captures output from `Console.WriteLine`, etc. This is because it now runs tests in parallel, in multiple threads, and there's no way of knowing what test the output comes from. It is still possible to capture output, but you need to use xunit's `ITestOutputHelper` in order to do so. See the [xunit docs](http://xunit.github.io/docs/capturing-output.html) for more details.